# ASP.NET MVC 5: how to force image ETAG to be recalculated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, etag

I am developing a website where a user might change his profile image.
This profile image has a fixed name such as "profile####.jpg" (where #### corresponds to the user's profile id).

In other words, if the user's profile id is "123", the image name will always be: "profile123.jpg".

The problem I am facing is that when the user changes his profile image, the new version of the image is not refreshed the next time the page is displayed (the "old" version of profile123.jpg is still used (from disk cache).

Having a look at the network communication, I have this:

profile123.jpg   status 200   type jpeg  ETag "e5b8c99974a3d31:0"

When I directly change the image source (in Chrome developer tools / Elements pane) to "profile123.jpg?some_sand", I obtain:

profile123.jpg?some_sand  status 200  type jpeg  ETag "2479c550dcad31:0".

and I have the correct profile image displayed.

Now the question:

I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2 MVC 5 (**NOT ASP.NET Core**)

How can I set up a correct ETag filter on static files (such as images), which would ensure that each time I change an image (keeping its name unchanged), the new version is being downloaded and displayed?

Many thanks

Comment: Instead of using `profile123.jpg`, why not use the format  like `profile{TimeStampWhereProfileLastUpdated}.jpg` ? You probably need a seperate column in the User table to store the profile picture name (if you are currently appending simply the user id)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a class that can be accessed from the Razor View (by making sure it's namespace is referenced in the View web.config) like so:-

```
public class CacheBreaker
{
    public static string VersionTag(string rootRelativePath)
    {
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] == null)
        {
            var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~" + rootRelativePath);
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                return rootRelativePath;
            }

            var result = rootRelativePath + "?v=" + Encryption.GenerateMD5(File.GetLastWriteTime(path).Ticks.ToString());
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(rootRelativePath, result, new CacheDependency(path));
        }

        return HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] as string;
    }
}
```

you can use this reference in the View to generate a fingerprint for the image:

```
<img src="@CacheBreaker.VersionTag(Url.Content("~/Path/To/Image/profile123.jpg"))" />
```

that generates:

```
<img src="/Path/To/Image/profile123.jpg?v=5276dc5d07eaf51013a48a1e539def2b">
```

that will be updated every time the image changes.

(This code is a modified version of the code in a [Mads Kristensen's blog](https://madskristensen.net/blog/cache-busting-in-aspnet/), but based upon it, where you can find more details of the principles behind this approach.)